# MySQL query: How to get the trending posts ordered by latest submission date

Tags: mysql, date, join, sql-order-by, having-clause

I am trying to get the latest trending posts, which are suppose to be the post with the highest **number of Views**, and for that I am using the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.date,
    COUNT(v.post_id) views 
FROM 
    posts p 
    JOIN posts_views v ON v.post_id = p.id 
GROUP BY v.post_id 
ORDER BY views DESC, p.date DESC
```

`posts.date` is Post submission date.

This query is supposed to be getting the Latest (highest Viewed) Posts, but unfortunately, the result I am getting from this query is always the highest **Views** between posts, regardless of how old the post which has a higher number of **Views**.

I need the query to get the posts that were added within a month sorted by the number of views, then reorder them according to the date submission of each post. The list should bring first the post that has a higher number of views but a newer date of submission. And a case scenario would be is a post that is not on top of the number of views would be first because it is a new post but has a challenging number of views. , such as:

```
ORDER  ID   VIEWS   DATE
1      23   55      2018/12/01
2      45   77      2018/07/07
3      14   45      2018/06/05
```

---

*posts* table structure:

```
id   title   date
65   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2    1543346735
67   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3    1543346256
66   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4    1543346253
68   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 5    1543376617
```

*posts_views* table structure:

```
id   post_id  ip            date
1    65       44.55.36.13   1543346735
5    67       46.54.36.51   1543347256
4    66       43.55.36.51   1543347253
6    68       48.66.36.01   1543377617
```

Comment: So you want only x results, which are the highest viewed, but in date order? Or what exactly? If that, then order by views, limit, make into a subquery and order by date

Comment: But what is the exact definition of “highest yet new”?

Comment: I need it to be in a single query if possible. I need the query to get the highest viewed posts among the latest submitted ones.

Comment: You’ll have to define “latest.” It needs to be something you can specifically define. Last week? Last month? Last year? Weight the view count based on age? Figure out a mathematical or logical formula first to define how it should be determined

Comment: I mean by latest "Last Week", yes I should weight the views count based on the age of the post?

Comment: Highest viewed needs also a threshold!

Comment: Highest viewed means: the highest number of views count.

Answer (score 2):

**If** you are looking to output the list of posts that were submitted over last week with their view count, ordered by descending submission date, then :

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, COUNT(v.post_id) views 
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN posts_views v ON v.post_id = p.id 
WHERE p.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY v.post_id 
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

You might want to limit the number of results by adding a `LIMIT` clause at the very end of the query, like `LIMIT 50` for the first 50 rows.

Another option would be to display only posts having at least *N* views with a `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, COUNT(v.post_id) views 
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN posts_views v ON v.post_id = p.id 
WHERE p.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY v.post_id 
HAVING COUNT(v.post_id) > 10
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

After all the comments finally providing a more explicit what you want, I would start by getting ONLY those Post IDs that are WITHIN the time period you care about first.  This distinct list can then be joined to the master "posts" table so you are not wasting time counting records of IDs that have no activity in weeks, months or even years..

Also, since you have not provided any table structure for the post_views table, I would have to assume the entry has a date/time... You could have 1 single post, but 30 people view over several days, so you would probably have a date on that table -- assuming such column name

```
select
      PQ.Post_ID,
      PQ.ViewCount,
      PQ.MostRecentViewDate,
      P.Date as OriginalPostDate  
   from
   ( select 
           v1.post_id,
           count(*) as viewCount,
           max( pv.viewDate ) as MostRecentViewDate
        from
           post_views pv
        where
           pv.viewDate >= now() - Interval 1 week
        group by
           pv.post_id 
        having
           count(*) > 10
        order by
           count(*) desc ) PQ
      JOIN posts p
         on PQ.Post_ID = P.id
```

For future, its also good to post structures of tables that are critical to clarify your point.  If you have 50 columns, you may only need to show 3-4 associated with query, only show that of importance to get your answer.

Comment: What is OriginalPostDate for if it is not used in the the query?

Comment: I need to query to get the posts that were added within a month sorted by the number of views, then reorder them according to the date submission of each post. The list should bring first the post that has a higher number of views but a newer date of submission. And a case scenario would be is a post that is not on top of the number of views would be first because it is a new post but has a challenging number of views.